# SELECT after Natural Sort - MySQL

Tags: mysql, natural-sort

I have a table which contains the following data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS names;
CREATE TABLE names(itemName varchar(20));
INSERT INTO names (itemName) VALUES
('A01'),
('A99'),
('AA01'),
('AAA99'),
('Z01'),
('M01'),
('M58'),
('AM52'),
('AB01'),
('AZ52'),
('AY25');
```

I want to be able to select from this table, in a **Natural Sorted** format, all the `itemNames` between a range, say, `A01` and `AM58`. Therefore, values such as `AAA99, AY25 and AZ52` do not constitute a valid result set, and the expected result would be:

```
    A01
    A99
    M01
    M58
    Z01
    AA01
    AB01
    AM52
```

With that in mind, the closest that I've been able to get to this is, using the following query:

```
SELECT x.itemName AS itemName__x, @min, @max FROM
    (
        SELECT @count := @count + 1 as seq, itemName, 
            CASE WHEN itemName = 'A01'
                    THEN @min := @count
                 WHEN itemName = 'AM52'
                    THEN @max := @count
                 ELSE
                    @count
                 END AS minmax
            FROM names 
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @count := 0) c 
            WHERE LENGTH(itemName) <= 4 
        ORDER BY LENGTH(itemName), itemName
    ) x 
    WHERE x.minmax BETWEEN @min AND @max;
```

This produces the correct result.
However, the only problem is, it expects the lower and upper bounds to match exactly in the table records. Ideally, I'd like it to work like a range: `BETWEEN "A01" AND "AM58"` (i.e. in this case, not having to specify `AM52` exactly), except with the natural sorting order preserved.

Here's the rextester link for a quick data set-up:
https://rextester.com/FXCP37816

Any suggestions that could help in making this a little flexible, please?
Or, any other alternative approach that might work?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to explain what `Natural Sorted` means here.  It certainly isn't lexicographical sorting of any kind.

Comment: Is the numeric part always 2 chars long?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, if I can explain it with an example, then the output of Natural Sort would be equivalent to what `ORDER BY LENGTH(itemName), itemName` will produce, though with some range filters. So, in this case, range `A01` to `M58` shouldn't include values such as `AA01`, which would otherwise be included if we just deployed `ORDER BY itemName`. Hope I'm making sense?

Comment: Are there always two digits?

Comment: Hi @forpas. No, neither the alphabetic part, nor the numeric part is guaranteed to be of any particular length. However, the numeric part will always be preceded by the alphabets.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, no, unfortunately not.

Comment: If the "range" be `A01` to `AM58`, then I don't see why `AA01` would not be included as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's an error on my part. `AAA99`, `AY25` and `AZ5` are supposed to be out of the range. I'll make that correction in the question body too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `names`
ORDER BY 
LENGTH(itemName) - LENGTH(REVERSE(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(itemName) AS UNSIGNED) AS CHAR))),
itemName, REVERSE(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(itemName) AS UNSIGNED) AS CHAR)) + 0
```